# Expectation of bilinear form squared with probabilistic matrix

Tags: probability, matrices, expected-value

Given a bilinear form $a^T P b$ where $P$ is a probabilistic matrix with known expectation $\mathbb{E}[P] = A$, and $a,b$ are some vectors.

**Question:** Can we somehow simplify:

$$ \mathbb{E}[(a^T P b)^2] $$

My first step is
$$\mathbb{E}[(a^T P b)^2] = \mathbb{E}[a^T P b b^T P^T a] $$
but I now face the issue of not knowing how to pull the expectation inside because the term is quadratic in $P$.

If it helps, a further assumptions on $P$ could be that it is symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to write $a^\top P b = \sum_i \sum_j P_{ij} a_i b_j$ and
$$(a^\top P b)^2 = \sum_i \sum_j \sum_k \sum_\ell P_{ij} P_{k\ell} a_i b_j a_k b_\ell.$$

From here, it is clear that you need to know $E[P_{ij} P_{k\ell}]$ for every $i,j,k,\ell$; equivalently, you need the variance of every entry of $P$ as well as the covariance between any two entries of $P$. Knowing "$E[P] = A$" and "$P$ is symmetric"  is not enough information.

---

Assuming independence of entries (aside from the constraint that $P$ is symmetric),

$$E[P_{ij} P_{k\ell}] = \begin{cases}
E[P_{ij}^2] = \sigma^2 + A_{ij}^2 & (i,j) = (k,\ell) \text{ or } (i,j) = (\ell, k)
\\
E[P_{ij}]E[P_{k\ell}] = A_{ij} A_{k\ell} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I think this implies $(a^\top P b)^2 = (a^\top A b)^2 + \sigma^2 \sum_i \sum_j (a_i^2 b_j^2 + a_i a_j b_i b_j)$, but I haven't checked this carefully.

---

If there is no symmetry assumption, then
$$E[P_{ij} P_{k\ell}] = \begin{cases}
E[P_{ij}^2] = \sigma^2 + A_{ij}^2 & (i,j) = (k,\ell)
\\
E[P_{ij}]E[P_{k\ell}] = A_{ij} A_{k\ell} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
which implies $(a^\top P b)^2 = (a^\top A b)^2 + \sigma^2 \sum_i \sum_j a_i^2 b_j^2$.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good way to see which assumptions would help. So if we assume independence between the entries of $P$ and assume the variance is known (say, it is $\sigma$ for all entries) - is there now a good way to write it?

Comment: @black Updated my answer